# Analog to .* for tensor/ vector multiplications in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I am generalizing a 1-D numerical method to 2-D and have run into an inconvenience. I was previously scaling each row in an array by using b.*A, where b is a (nx1) vector and A is an (nxm) array.

Is there a slick operation to extend this to a tensor? Let's say B is (nxm1xm2). When I try to sort out how to do b.*B I inevitably throw an "Array dimensions must match for binary array op." error.

I would rather use a builtin method of some kind or a cute way of mapping the multiplication function rather than brute forcing it with a for loop to keep the code clean and reasonably optimal.

To clarify

```
%I commonly use this product
A=[1,1,1;2,2,2;1,1,1];
b=[1;2;3];

b.*A

%I would like something similar to this which would multiply b(i) with B(:,:,i)
B=zeros(2,2,3);

B(:,:,1)=1;
B(:,:,2)=1;
B(:,:,3)=1;

b.*B
```

Outputs

```
ans =

     1     1     1
     4     4     4
     3     3     3

Array dimensions must match for binary array op.

Error in script4question (line 14)
b.*B
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the sizes match in each dimension. This means that the size in each dimension needs to be either the same as in the other array, or `1`. In the latter case [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) replicates the array with size 1 along that dimension as needed.

In your example, `b` is 3×1(×1) and `B` is 2×2×3, so their sizes don't match. To achieve what you want you need to turn `b` into a 1×1×3 vector, using either [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), [`shiftdim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html) or [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
reshape(b, 1, 1, []).*B
```

For Matlab versions older than R2016b there is no implicit expansion. In that case you can obtain the same result using [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
bsxfun(@times, reshape(b, 1, 1, []), B)
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you! Edited

Comment: Many thanks! This sheds some light on things.

Comment: @nrs Glad I could help. And welcome to the site!